# English term for aggressive street seller?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests, slang

Is there an English term for the type of street seller who aggressively sells his products? The type who yell after you and may follow you as you walk down the street?

Comment: Lucky-lucky man. ("Hey, where are you from my friend?")

Answer (score 35):

We refer to that salesman as a [***hawker***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hawker):

> A person who travels about selling goods, typically advertising them
>   by shouting:

I have always carried the word picture of a *hawker* swooping down to seize his customer with that shrill falcon scream, but the two *hawks* are homophones from different semantic roots:

> ***hawk***
>
> (n.)  c.1300, hauk, earlier havek (c.1200),
>
> from Old English hafoc (W. Saxon), heafuc (Mercian), heafoc, from
>   **Proto-Germanic** * ***habukaz***
>
> (cognates: Old Norse haukr, Old Saxon habuc, Middle Dutch havik, Old
>   High German habuh, German Habicht "hawk"),
>
> from a root meaning "to seize," from PIE *kap- "to grasp" (cognates:
>   Russian kobec "a kind of falcon;" see capable).
>
> ***hawk***
>
> (v.1)  "to sell in the open, peddle," late 15c.,
>
> back-formation from hawker "itinerant vendor" (c.1400),
>
> from Middle Low German höken "to peddle, carry on the back, squat,"
>
> from **Proto-Germanic * *huk*-**.
>
> Related: Hawked; hawking. Despite the etymological connection with
>   stooping under a burden on one's back, a hawker is technically
>   distinguished from a peddler by use of a horse and cart or a van.

From the same peddling roots, [***huckster***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/huckster) implies more aggressive than a hawker, and even a bit devious:

> A person who sells in an aggressive or ruthless way.

Comment: You were snagged in the same etymological trap I was, @LittleEva. Be Free!

Comment: Polysemous: multiple meanings; homophonous: same sounds, distinct meanings. Yet "hawk' still carries the "raptor" connotation in the popular mind. I'm flying free, though. thanks.

Comment: In the Mid-Atlantic US, 'huckster' would be more common. (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/huckster)

Answer (score 25):

Many tourist guidebooks will warn you against the *[tout](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tout)* [all dictionary definitions below are from AHD]:

> **tout**, *n.* 1. One who solicits customers brazenly or persistently:
>
> > "The administration of the nation's literary affairs falls naturally into the hands of touts and thieves" (Lewis H. Lapham).

- *A British tourist who was murdered … was seen with a travel tout shortly before he “disappeared”.* — [*The Independent*](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/andrew-roddick-murder-dead-uk-tourist-last-seen-in-company-of-indian-tout-9302592.html)
- *But travelers have been complaining for nearly a millennium about Cairo's touts and scams and souvenir hawkers.* — [*The New York Times*](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/04/11/travel/frugal-traveler-teeming-tempting-cairo.html)

*Tout* has a number of uses, however— in Northern Ireland and Scotland it refers to an informer, in Britain in general it apparently refers to what Americans would term a *scalper* (someone who buys up event tickets and resells them for profit), and in North America it can refer to someone offering racing tips to gamblers. Context is therefore important.

Another option is *[hawker](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hawker)*, and evidently *crier*:

> **hawker**, *n.* One who sells goods aggressively, especially by calling out. Also called *crier*.

A *[pusher](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=pusher)*, as might be guessed, is also in the business of thrusting a product or service upon you. The word is more pejorative than *tout* or *hawker*. I would couple this with the type of wares— *insurance pusher*, *Microsoft pusher*, *Jesus pusher*— as the word by itself is closely associated with a particular street trade:

> **pusher**, *n.* 2. *Slang* One who sells drugs illegally.

If the salesman is himself suspect, beyond the ethicality of the product, you might say he is a *[huckster](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=huckster)*— a seller who is dishonest as well as aggressive:

> **huckster**, *n.* 1. One who sells wares or provisions in the street; a peddler or hawker. 2. One who uses aggressive, showy, and sometimes devious methods to promote or sell a product.

For audiences who dislike being approached by strangers for a sale, even relatively neutral terms like *peddler*, *costermonger*, or even *street vendor* can do the trick. *He's a fruit peddler* is descriptive, but *He's such a fruit peddler!* is uncomplimentary.

Comment: The noun "tout" has the connotation of somebody who's angling for commission (taxi tout, hotel tour, etc), whereas a "hawker" is selling something directly (street hawker, drink hawker, etc).

Comment: @jpatokal Perhaps, but they're still selling, and still in your face. OP didn't restrict by compensation mechanism.

Comment: Also "pitch man", " barker"

Comment: @choster "street seller who aggressively sells *his* products" sounds closer to the hawker end of the spectrum to me.

Comment: @jpatokal They're "his" regardless of ownership. They probably belong to the boss.

Comment: I didn't know that tout was a noun.  I've only ever heard it as an act, like "He was touting the advantages of an object-oriented approach."   Or "touting one's wares" as in the indignant quote from Bug's Life, "touting your wares as a talent scout".  I don't think I would know what someone meant if they called a person a tout (before reading this, I mean).  I wonder if it's more common in British English?  AHD doesn't give that noun form the "Chiefly British" designation, but I'm pretty sure I've never heard it used in the US.

Comment: @msouth English is famously flexible regarding word usage; verbs can be nouned just as nouns can be verbed.

Comment: Barker was what I thought of as well.  As in a carnival barker.  However, I've never had a barker follow me, but I certainly have had touts, hawkers, pimps, hucksters, and hustlers do so in various parts of the world.  The worst was in Karachi, Pakistan, where T-shirt hawkers would sneak up from behind, pull one of their shirts over your head and arms, and then demand payment.  This was a bit disconcerting, but the fabric was incredibly thin so I was able to literally flex my way out of it, rending the seams and ruining the shirt.  I figured it was his problem and walked away.  He followed.

Answer (score 13):

**Hustler** -

> hus·tle
>   (hŭs′əl)
>   v. hus·tled, hus·tling, hus·tles
>   v.intr.
>   1. To move or act energetically and rapidly: We hustled to get dinner ready on time.
>   2. To push or force one's way.
>   3. To act aggressively, especially in business dealings.

It obviously has additional meanings, but it fits and its more colloquial than other suggestions I saw here so far. If I had to use something that people would know what I'm talking about, I'd go with this.

Comment: _Huckster_ is every bit as colloquial as _hustler_, and it has the added advantage of not implying that the vendor is trying to sell you… well, himself.

Comment: Maybe on the Canterbury market, elsewhere it didn't strike big

Comment: sounds dated, is all I'm saying - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Swindlers,_Hucksters_and_Snake_Oil_Salesman_-_Hype_and_Hope_Marketing_Anti-Aging_Products_to_Seniors.pdf

Comment: Doesn't sound dated to me—I've heard it used in normal conversation, and I've used it myself. _Hustler_ in this sense sounds more dated to my ear. But in many contexts, I would consider _hustler_ inappropriate just because of ambiguity. “The worst thing about this city is all the hustlers always badgering you in the streets all the time”, for instance, would I wager be interpreted by most as referring to male prostitutes, not fruit vendors.

Comment: You have no idea what the context is, and still you're insisting. For the sake of argument you used an ambiguous context to fit it in.

Comment: +1, Ngram query: [Huckster, Hustler](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Huckster%2CHustler&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHuckster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHustler%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'm not _insisting_ on anything. I'm saying that to me, _hustler_ sounds more old-fashioned in the sense being discussed here than _huckster_ (or especially _hawker_) does. It also has the disadvantage that in many contexts, it is ambiguous, which means I would likely avoid using it “[i]f I had to use something that people would know what I'm talking about”. The fact that we don't know the context is exactly why it is important to mention that there is ambiguity in some (if not most) contexts.

Comment: Hustler has been more popular in writing  since the 1960's, and currently about 2x more common, but its use for prostitution skews the comparison. For accuracy of communication *colloquial* is not the same as *popular*, @joeav. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/colloquial Good answer, though you might do well to substitute *familiar* for *colloquial*.

Comment: @ScotM from oxford: "used in ordinary or familiar conversation; not formal or literary" seems like what I was going for?

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - I'm not disagreeing with you either, the popularity of a term may or may not be relevant to a user's need, and "street hustler" *definitely* connotes with 'male prostitute".

Answer (score 7):

A [huckster](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Huckster):

> - One who uses aggressive, showy, and sometimes devious methods to promote or sell a product.

(TFD)

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is mountebank. Others: Hustler. Panhandler. Hawker.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. References or examples would be helpful to support your answer. As I understand the terms, a *mountebank* is more of a cheat than a loud or aggressive salesman, and *panhandler* is a soft word for a *beggar*.

Comment: Hi Choster. I agree with you entirely and did not realize the forum etiquette encouraged definitions or, at least, examples. The only word most folks won't be familiar with is mountebank; and it is my understanding the word refers colloquially to someone who is a kind of cheat (specifically in relation to a sale). Richard Dawkins once called someone he was debating "a prating mountebank." With the prating modifier in place, I think the phrase fits the OP's needs quite well.

Comment: I mean, maybe it's a little on the edge of description, but mountebank is related to commerce and it's certainly unique. Not sure what the OP wants or if a King's English word like mountebank is really appropriate but I like that word. It's punchy.